# Converting UNICODE characters to HTML entity in JSON string that is returned via Spring MVC @ResponseBody

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables

I am writing a Spring MVC application where I make a AJAX call from a JSP which would return a JSON string. Some text in the JSON string would contains special characters, for example:

Bullet character with unicode 8226 or 
Punctuation characters like 
Apostrophe (Quote) character with unicode 8217

In my JSP, when I populate textareas with such characters, it usually holds its original form and displays well. However, I am using Datatables Editor in some parts of my application, and the above characters are displayed as ? (question mark) in the grid.

I figure, the solution would be to convert the unicode characters into HTML entities when forming the JSON string. For example, in the controller, if I scan my string for presence of 8226 character and replace it with • and send this JSON string to Datatables grid, then I can properly see the bullet characters.

**My question is: Is there any way in Spring MVC, or other tools, to detect presence of unicode characters greater than 256, and replace them with HTML entities at the time that the JSON string is returned?** There are many AJAX calls that return JSON string in my application, and it would be some work to invoke conversion tools in every `@RequestMapping` method. I was thinking if there could be a Spring interceptor that could do this conversion. Or are there any strategies in `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` to take care of this conversion?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the mapping that I have in my `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/trips/{projectId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProjectTrips(@PathVariable BigInteger projectId) throws IOException {
        return projectTripReportGridService.getGridData(projectId);
    }
```

and the method `projectTripReportGridService.getGridData` is:

```
public String getGridData(BigInteger projectId) throws IOException {

        List<ProjectTripReport> entityViews;

        entityViews = projectTripReportRepo.findAllByProjectId(projectId);

        for (ProjectTripReport si : entityViews) {
            if(si.getTripReport().indexOf(8226) > 0){
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String tempReport = "";
                String wholeString = si.getTripReport();
                while(wholeString.indexOf(8226) > 0){
                    tempReport = wholeString.substring(0, wholeString.indexOf(8226));
                    sb.append(tempReport);
                    sb.append("&bull;");
                    wholeString = wholeString.substring(wholeString.indexOf(8226) + 1);
                }
                sb.append(wholeString);
                si.setTripReport(sb.toString());
            }
}
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy[]{new OneToManyExclusionStrategy(), new JpaExclusionStrategy()}).create();
return gson.toJson(gson.toJsonTree(entityViews));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what I was asking in my question was how to have JSON response 'encoded' in UTF-8 from a central location in the application for 'all' JSON response strings. And below is the answer. The following script needs to be added in springConfig.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
            <list>
                <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```